# Why does ng serve throw error in angular?

Tags: angular

I am getting below error when run using `ng serve`.

```
ERROR in Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'OpaqueToken', function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function, resolving symbol FirebaseUserConfig in C:/Users/mohammad/Desktop/My Programming World/My SPA/My Angualr/pinterest/node_modules/angularfire2/tokens.d.ts, resolving symbol AngularFireModule.initializeApp in C:/Users/mohammad/Desktop/My Programming World/My SPA/My Angualr/pinterest/node_modules/angularfire2/angularfire2.d.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in C:/Users/mohammad/Desktop/My Programming World/My SPA/My Angualr/pinterest/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in C:/Users/mohammad/Desktop/My Programming World/My SPA/My Angualr/pinterest/src/app/app.module.ts
    at syntaxError (C:\Users\mohammad\Desktop\My Programming World\My SPA\My Angualr\pinterest\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:1513:34)
    at simplifyInContext (C:\Users\mohammad\Desktop\My Programming World\My SPA\My Angualr\pinterest\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:23316:23)
    at StaticReflector.simplify (C:\Users\mohammad\Desktop\My Programming World\My SPA\My Angualr\pinterest\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:23328:13)
    at StaticReflector.annotations (C:\Users\mohammad\Desktop\My Programming World\My SPA\My Angualr\pinterest\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:22794:60)
    at _getNgModuleMetadata (C:\Users\mohammad\Desktop\My Programming World\My SPA\My Angualr\pinterest\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:126:31)
    at _extractLazyRoutesFromStaticModule (C:\Users\mohammad\Desktop\My Programming World\My SPA\My Angualr\pinterest\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:101:26)
    at Object.listLazyRoutesOfModule (C:\Users\mohammad\Desktop\My Programming World\My SPA\My Angualr\pinterest\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:52:22)
    at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.listLazyRoutes (C:\Users\mohammad\Desktop\My Programming World\My SPA\My Angualr\pinterest\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_api.js:79:39)
    at AotPlugin._getLazyRoutesFromNgtools (C:\Users\mohammad\Desktop\My Programming World\My SPA\My Angualr\pinterest\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:240:66)
    at C:\Users\mohammad\Desktop\My Programming World\My SPA\My Angualr\pinterest\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:493:24
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

I tired removing firebase Angular but no luck

The project comes from https://github.com/aviabird/pinterest/issues
Any reason ?

Answer (score 0):

**`ng serve` displaying the error not causing the**

The error comes from `OpaqueToken` as mentioned in the error message. `ng server` is just showing the error message as it happened.

Error:

> Calling function 'OpaqueToken', function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function, resolving symbol FirebaseUserConfig in C:/Users/mohammad/Desktop/My Programming World/My SPA/My Angualr/pinterest/node_modules/angularfire2/tokens.d.ts, resolving symbol AngularFireModule.initializeApp in

Comment: Can I fix the issue ? I debuged plugin.js and the error comes in  this._discoveredLazyRoutes = this.firstRun
                ? this._getLazyRoutesFromNgtools()
                : this._findLazyRoutesInAst();

Comment: No sure what is the issue thought, try to replace this with something or read about `OpaqueToken`. I think if you are using angular 8 or later, its depreciated. 
 So try to use older angular or replace something.

Comment: Yes I think it version issue becuase the project in githup was created in angualr 1 and I am running angualr 8

Comment: that is the issue. try something new

Comment: @ Aniruddha Das ok